# Can't ping two machines through a router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iptables, ping

On my access point connected to Internet, machine 1 (192.168.43.12) and machine 2 (192.168.43.153) are connected through their wireless NIC.
Through a switch, machine 2 (192.168.0.1) is also connected to machine 3 (192.168.0.101).

Machine 2 is configured to share Internet connection to machine 3:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -o wlp3s0 -i eno1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -F POSTROUTING
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
sudo /etc/init.d/dnsmasq start
```

On machine 3, `traceroute` returns:

```
traceroute to google.com (216.58.198.206), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  sc500 (192.168.0.1)  0.529 ms  0.432 ms  0.373 ms
 2  * * *
 3  10.28.0.1 (10.28.0.1)  35.665 ms  36.062 ms  36.006 ms
 4  * * *
 5  194.149.164.94 (194.149.164.94)  35.965 ms  35.909 ms  31.021 ms
 6  72.14.221.62 (72.14.221.62)  35.607 ms  33.460 ms  33.599 ms
 7  108.170.244.161 (108.170.244.161)  33.702 ms  19.679 ms  17.077 ms
 8  108.170.234.51 (108.170.234.51)  18.306 ms  27.571 ms  28.029 ms
 9  par10s27-in-f206.1e100.net (216.58.198.206)  27.975 ms  29.825 ms  27.862 ms
```

However, from machine 1, I can't ping anyone on 192.168.0.X. I don't understand why and how can it be achievable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured machine 2 to do network address translation (NAT) for anyone on the 192.168.0.0/24 network. In other words, you've instructed machine 2 to pretend to everyone else that there's really no 192.168.0.0/24 network, but it's all coming machine 2. (That's what "sharing an internet connection" does). The flip side of this pretension is that of course no one on 192.168.0.0/24 is reachable from the outside via machine 2.

The proper setup would be to either

(1) have a single segment (192.168.43.0/24), i.e. use a bridge on machine2. But bridging a WLAN station to LAN is difficult (see other recent questions).

(2) configure your main router (the gateway on 192.168.43.0/24) to do the NAT towards your ISP for a bigger range (say, 192.168.42.0/23), manage 192.168.43.0/24 on WLAN as before, configure machine 2 without NAT to just forward and route packets between 192.168.42.0/24 and 192.168.43.0/24, and setup static routes whereever needed.

(3) keep everything as it is, accept that you can't access 192.168.0.0/24 by IP, but set up port forwarding for a few important services you want to reach on 192.168.0.0/24.

Comment: I ended up by launching the access point on machine 2, which simplifies a lot.